# Editing a mongoDB item not updating but not receiving an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am desperate for some help with an issue I am having updating an item in a mongoDB database. I am creating a simple note application using nodeJS and I have set it up to add notes and remove notes to and from the database with no issues.

When I try to edit notes however, the update does not persist to the database. I dont get an error back and when I console.log the result it displays the correct data but just wont seem to push it to the data base. I have been using mongoose and findByIdAndUpdate. Here is the JavaScript code for my update route

```
app.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
Note.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.note, (err, updatedNote) => {

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.redirect(`/${req.params.id}`);
        console.log(req.params.id);
        console.log(req.body.note);
        console.log("note updated");
    }
});
```

});

As I mentioned, I dont get any error and the console.logs return the correct id and updated content. All my routes take me to the place so I don't believe there is an issue with them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can also provide more code if needed

Thanks in advance

Will

Comment: What's in `updatedNote`?

Comment: updetedNote is what is returned after the update, when I console.log it no update has been made, it is still the original content. I have used this exact same approach on another app and it works fine. Really struggling to see what the issue is and the fact that I dont get an error is making it really hard to spot what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating in MongoDB, you have to reference the field you are trying to update. Your code should look like this

```
app.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
Note.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {text: req.body.note}, (err, updatedNote) => {

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.redirect(`/${req.params.id}`);
        console.log(req.params.id);
        console.log(req.body.note);
        console.log("note updated");
    }
});
});
```

PS: I am hoping the field in the DB model is called `text`

---

To make the code look sexier, you can switch it to Async/Await

```
app.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
       let updatedNote = await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {text: 
       req.body.note}, {new: true}).catch(err => console.log(err))

        res.redirect(`/${req.params.id}`);
        console.log(req.params.id);
        console.log(req.body.note);
        console.log("note updated");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That `updatedNote` is the same as before the update is expected behavior – see the [mongooe docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate):

> By default, findOneAndUpdate() returns the document as it was before
>   update was applied. If you set new: true, findOneAndUpdate() will
>   instead give you the object after update was applied.

This does not mean the update did not take place.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still didnt work. Also I was using the findByIdAndUpdate method rather than findOneAndUpdate(). I am just really confused as the exact same approach has worked fine for me on several other applications